# How to update columns based on column name

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a table with several sets of columns that share suffixes, for example: `column_foo`

I need to update all columns that have the suffix "foo" at once, without having to list them after `SET` in my command line.

So, basically, if I were to write the command line literally, it'd be something like this:

"Update myTable set (all columns which name contains 'foo') = value where id = 1".

How do I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL for that. Or fix your data model. This really sounds as if all those columns really should be one column but multiple rows

Comment: Actually I think I should have used array-type columns instead of multiple columns sharing some suffix. The task described in my question is an one-time fix I need to perform in my table. I intend to modify this table using arrays as soon as I have the time for it.